# How to extract paragraphs containing keyword from pdf of novel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to extract paragraphs from a novel containing a particular keyword but this is not running properly. open to any suggestions even alternative programs/modules but am limited to python. code below:

```
import PyPDF2
import re
pattern = ('.', 'thought', 'night', 'face', '.')
fileName = input('ethanfrome22.pdf')
object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(fileName)
numPages = object.getNumPages()
for i in range(0, numPages):
    pageObj = object.getPage(i)
    text = pageObj.extractText() 
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, text):
        print(f'Page no: {i} | Match: {match}')
```

Comment: @InhirCode i reposted the question

Comment: What's the problem? is the problem in the extracted text of the pdf file or in the matching that you are using?

Comment: I'm not totally sure, I just want it to output paragraphs that contain those keywords, and nothing else.. so that I can then use it interchangeably for anything I'm interested in. right now it only outputs the title of the document

Comment: containing them individually is just as ideal. someone is advising me on using a digital version of the text to begin with--that one is a scan of a first edition.. since this is for literary interpretation, paragraphs or chunks of lines would be best so I can use them as analysis passages

Comment: "open to any suggestions even alternative programs/modules but am limited to python. code below"

Then you are not open. Good luck.